# Why $\omega<2^{\omega}$ but $\omega^{\omega}\sim\omega$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I understand the Cantor's proof for why $S<2^S$, but also we know that ordinals $\omega\sim\omega^2\sim\omega^3...$. This approaches to $\omega^{\omega}$, what should be at least not less than $2^{\omega}$. What do I miss with this logic?

Comment: This contradicts [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488776/why-is-2-omega-not-a-larger-cardinal-then-omega?rq=1).

Comment: The left one is *cardinal* exponentiation, while the right is *ordinal* exponentiation. These are *not* the same.

Comment: Because ordinal exponentiation is defined differently than is cardinal exponentiation.  If you were using ordinal exponentiation, you'd find that $2^\omega$ is countable.

Comment: If you are performing **ordinal** exponentiation, then $2^\omega=\omega$. This is very different from **cardinal** exponentiation.

Comment: I maintain it is **bad** to write $\omega$ when you mean $\aleph_0$, especially if you also use notation $a^b$ for both exponentiation of ordinals and exponentiation of ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two different notions of exponentiation: the cardinal exponentiation and the ordinal exponentiation.

$2^\omega$ can mean either

1. The cardinality of the power set of $\omega$ (or the set of functions $\omega\to 2$), or
2. The ordinal number corresponding to the order type of finite binary sequences, ordered lexicographically.

The latter is a countably infinite ordinal (which is, in fact, equal to $\omega$, so it also happens to be cardinal). The former is an uncountable cardinal, the continuum.

Likewise, $\omega^\omega$ can mean one of the two:

1. The cardinality of the set of functions $\omega\to \omega$,
2. The ordinal number corresponding to the order type of finite sequences with values in $\omega$.

Here, the former is a cardinal number (in fact, equal to the continuum), while the latter is a countable ordinal (which is strictly between $\omega$ and the continuum).

Especially when there is risk of confusion, it is good practice to use $\aleph_0$ when talking about $\omega$ as a cardinal (in particular, when you mean to use cardinal exponentiation), $\omega$ when you mean to talk about it as an ordinal, and $\mathbf N$ when you mean to talk about it as a set of integers. Then it would be pretty clear that $\aleph_0=\omega=2^\omega<\omega^\omega<2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ and $\omega\sim 2^\omega\sim \omega^\omega\not\sim 2^{\aleph_0}\sim \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $[2]$ instead of $2$?

Comment: Where? Why?${}{}$